# How to do a true strtoul? Wont intake an actual string

Tags: c++, binary, hex, strtol

Having an issue inputting an ACTUAL string to strtuol. The input string SHOULD be an unsigned binary value of 32 bits long.

Obviously, there is in issue with `InputString = apple;` but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue. any thoughts? This shouldnt be that difficult. not sure why I'm having such a hard time with it.

Thanks guys.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char InputString[40];
    char *pEnd = NULL;          // Required for strtol()
    string apple = "11111111110000000000101010101000";
    //cout << "Number? ";
    //cin >> InputString;
    InputString = apple;
    unsigned long x = strtoul(InputString, &pEnd, 2);     // String to long

    cout << hex << x << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you use [`std::stoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) instead? It takes a `std::string` directly.

Comment: Um, the input string should be a sequence of 32 **characters**, each being `1` or `0`. The string does not have a numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include :

```
#include<cstdlib> // for strtol()
#include<cstring> // for strncpy()
```

and then

```
 strncpy(InputString ,apple.c_str(),40); 
                            ^
                            |
                            convert to C ctring
```

Or simply,

`unsigned long x = strtoul(apple.c_str(), &pEnd, 2);`

Comment: Shouldn't you use strncpy to avoid buffer overflow? For that matter, why copy the string at all; why not use apple.c_str() directly in strtoul()?

Comment: Works perfect. and elimintaes the need to use `inputstring` thanks guys.

Comment: @cmonnats23 - while `strncpy` avoids overflowing the buffer, if the input string is the same size as the buffer `strncpy` does **not** append a terminating nul character and you have a garbage string.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to avoid the legacy-C functions and use the C++ standard functions:

```
string apple = "11111111110000000000101010101000";
unsigned long long x = std::stoull(apple, NULL, 2); // defined in <string>
```

NOTE:  `std::stoull` will actually call `::strtoull` internally, but it allows you to just deal with the `std::string` object instead of having to convert it to a C-style string.

Comment: I agree with this answer but `std::stoul` is a better match for the example code in the question.

Comment: @Blastfurnace If his string was 32 characters long, I would agree.  Since it is 33 characters long (and his current C-style string is 40 characters), a 64-bit version of the function is a better match.  They are in the same family of functions, however (and both are declared in `<string>`.